# OnDemand SQL update using pyspark for Role, user management

Tags: sql, azure, pyspark, azure-synapse, ondemand

I am trying to create ROLE based on the Groups coming in from Azure AAD groups and if they do not exist in DB. I am using the code below but it fails saying
"ParseException:
Operation not allowed: CREATE ROLE(line 1, pos 0)

== SQL ==
CREATE ROLE [ROLE_AZURE_AAD_GROUP]  AUTHORIZATION [dbo];
^^^"
"
What is the workaround?

```
for row in df_AADGroup.rdd.collect():
    #print('ROLE_' + row['Azure_AAD_Group_name'] + row['Azure_AAD_Group_UsageType'])
    if row['Azure_AAD_Group_UsageType'] == 'Functional':
        query = "select * from database_principals where name = 'ROLE_" + row['Azure_AAD_Group_name'] + "'"
        if spark.sql(query).count() == 0 :
            role_query = "CREATE ROLE [ROLE_" + row['Azure_AAD_Group_name'] + "]  AUTHORIZATION [dbo];"
            spark.sql(role_query)
        print('ROLE_' + row['Azure_AAD_Group_name'] + " does not exists")
```

Comment: If you're running a Synapse notebook, you are connected to a Spark database, not the serverless SQL pool (formerly known as SQL on-demand).  Just script out your SQL and run it as a SQL script in Synapse studio against your serverless instance.  Make sense?

Comment: I am in the process automation. There is a powershell script which pushes data from Azure AAD to Datalake. What I want next is to create the Roles corresponding to them in the database which do not exist in DB. That's why you see that CREATE ROLE...statement in the code above. I want to fire the CREATE ROLE to the DB from Synapse notebook for the role to be created in the database. This isn't working for me and I am looking out for different ways to do.